# I need help to find my ssd location

Tags: ssd

I installed an SSD called Lexar, it appeared on disk management but still cannot find it on my files and this pc, that means my laptop accepted but I cannot find it

Comment: Did you format it after you installed it?

Comment: What does it look like in Disk Management? Is it "online"? Does it have any partitions created on it?

Comment: Disk Management or diskpart should show you if your device is registering it. If not, ensure your have sufficient power.

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk Management and right-click on your SSD disk

[you may see this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nVp.png)

and click on Explorer to open your drive! ☺

if your Explorer was disabled (like this picture) this means your drive was not formatted(format it) or your drive letter was removed (add letter)

[Add new letter menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPNqM.png)